# Looking for help creating a code that works similar to auto-capitalization in bluej [has one answer but looking for further clarification]

Tags: java, computer-science, capitalization

I have to complete an assignment for my CS class where I develop a program to solve a problem. I want to make a code that will be able to capitalize the first letter of any sentence as well as holidays and names if possible. It can be very simple, as I am still very new to coding, and I will attach the instructions given to me on this post. I really just need a starting point, and I believe that I am supposed to have a client class as well. We use BlueJ for our coding with java. [CS Assignment Rubric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADVPS.png)

edit: [Updated Code-need months/holidays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvD8s.png) / [finished part of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnan4.png)

Comment: I have done this much so far and inserted a picture of my current code in an edit above, but I am still very confused as I have never used StringBuilder or Split and of unsure about how to continue. More help from anyone would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, how I would approach this:
Start by hardcoding sentences in a `StringBuilder` and capitalize the first character by using something like

```
yourString.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(yourString.charAt(0))
```

Then make a `String`-array with names and holidays.
Check word by word (hint: method `split(" ")` will be helpful here) and replace the first character of matching words with the `Character.toUpperCase()` method.
At last, scan the whole String for dots ('.') and replace the following letter with its upper case.
Somewhat like this: `yourString.setCharAt(<pos of dot> + 2, ...)`.
The `+2` is needed, as there is usually a space between sentences. Like so, but you'll figure it out!
Have fun coding!

Comment: I think that I got the capitalization for the the first letter of each sentence, but I do not understand how to do the months, holidays, or check for periods/dots and was wondering if you could try to explain more because I have very basic knowledge of java

Comment: The trick is using the `split()` method. For example, `str.split(" ")` returns an array of Strings, where each element is a word. (`String[] words = str.split(" ");`). You already hard-coded the "names" of the holidays, months and so on. What you need to do now is loop through `words` and check, if a word matches the lowercase of an holiday, and replace it with the upper case. For example:  `if(words[10].equals(holidays[0].toLowerCase())){ words[10] = holidays[0]; }`. After all words have been processed, create the final string (loop through `words`): `String finalString += words[<index>]` ...